# Unable to open HAXM device: ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have already insatlled HAXM but still I am not able to start avd, I got error evry time.

I tried all the answers in stack overflow nothing worked

```
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

15:00   Emulator: CPU acceleration status: Unable to open HAXM device: ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

15:00   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image]

Comment: open and edit with mark hardware acceleration true.

Comment: where i can do that @HemantParmar

Comment: Go to AVD devices list, click on device and edit it.

Comment: I am not getting hardware acceleration option

Answer (score 7):

In my case(Windows 10 Enterprise), disabling Hyper-V fixed it.

Steps to disable Hyper-V:

1. Hit the Windows Key and type “Turn Windows features on or off”.
2. Click on Turn Windows features on or off.
3. When the dialog appears, look for Hyper-V and deselect it.
4. Press OK and reboot.

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue on with Andorid Studio on Win10 Home. All sugestions I found were talkig about switchig off Hyper-V from Windows features. Win10 Home does not have that option.

The solution for my case was following:

1. Settings => Windows Security => Device Security => Core Isolatin Details
2. Memory Integrity: turn it off
3. Restart Windows

Comment: @TaaviTiitsu I am using Win10 enterprise and don't see this option. Any idea where to find?